# How to store 32 input paramaeters in a single solidity function with data types being string and bytes32?

Tags: ethereum

When I try to exceute a solidity smart conract function to store 32 input parameters, I am getting a stack too deep error.

To resolve that, at the middleware we have consolidated and created an array of bytes32 for 24 input parameters and the rest of the 8 parameters are of string datatype. But again we get the same stack too deep error.

How can I possibly exceute a function to store the 32 input parameters?

We are making use of solidity compiler version 0.4.25.

This is the basic skeletal of code

```
struct Sample {
    bytes32 key;
    string str1;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    string str8;
    byts32[] someArray; //23 elements 
}

mapping(bytes32 => Sample) sampleMap;

function set(bytes32 key,string str1,string str2,......,string 
str8,bytes32[] array) public returns(bool) {
    //set the values using sampleMap mapping;
    return true;
}

function get(bytes32 key) returns(bytes32 key,string str1,string 
str2,......,string str8,bytes32[] array) {
     //retrieve values from struct using sampleMap mapping
}
```

Comment: code or errors? Seems impossible to answer without them